# Angular Material - md-select - selected item in dropdown

Tags: angular, select, angular-material

I have a md-select dropdown with list of user names. I want the lead.id to be selected. How can I achieve this?

```
  <md-select formControlName="lead" ng-model="plan.lead.id" id="lead" style="min-width: 200px;">
                    <md-option *ngFor="let lead of users" [value]="lead.id">
                        {{lead.displayName}}
                    </md-option>
                </md-select>

getLead() {
        this.service.getLead(this.id)
            .subscribe(res => {
                this.plan = res;
                console.log("lead: " + this.plan.lead);     
            }); 
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to select an option via the code? Or get the id of an option once it was clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `ng-model`, which is AngularJS syntax. But you are not needing to use ngModel here, since you have a reactive form (??), and you can set the formcontrol with the value you have received. So when you have received your `plan`, you can set the value:

```
this.myForm.get('lead').setValue(this.plan.lead.id)
```

Your template:

```
<md-select formControlName="lead" id="lead" style="min-width: 200px;">
  <md-option *ngFor="let lead of users" [value]="lead.id">
      {{lead.displayName}}
 </md-option>
</md-select>
```

Wait a couple of seconds and in the **[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/P3AAzUui6xIg3VoKpICG?p=preview)** the value will be set.

Comment: This is what I was missing. Once I set this on the component, it worked beautifully. 

this.myForm.get('lead').setValue(this.plan.lead.id)

Comment: Great! Glad to hear! As a sidenote, ngModel is totally unneccessary (and discouraged) to use with reactive forms, the formcontrols replaces that in this case and should be used to set the values :) Other functions you can perform on form controls you have here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormControl-class.html Can be useful if you e.g need to reset value for a specific form control, so check that page out :) Furthermore, have a great day/evening/morning and happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you using reactive forms?

If so, despite the fact that you're using an incorrect syntax in `ng-model` (it should be `[(ngModel)]`), you shouldn't use it with reactive forms.

Use only `formControlName` or `[formControl]`.

Comment: I will add that a good reminder for the ngModel syntax is 'banana in a box', you'll probably not forget it :D